# Find the gradient of a function where a norm is involved

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find the gradient of a function in which a norm is involved, $F(x) = -\frac{1}{2}{\lVert  Ax-b \rVert}_2^2, \,\,\,A \in \mathbb{R}^{d,d} .$  I expressed the norm in terms of the inner product and the corresponding symmetric positive definite matrix $S$, $${\lVert  Ax-b \rVert}_2^2 = \langle Ax-b, Ax -b\rangle = (Ax-b)^tS(Ax-b)= x^tA^tSAx-x^tA^tb-b^tSAx+b^tSb.$$ The first expression at the right hand side can be written as $a_1x_1^2+...+a_dx_d^2.$ Thus we get $\nabla F(x) = 2ax^t - A^tb- b^tSA.$ The answer I should get is $\nabla F(x) = Ax -b.$

Can somebody provide some support in finding the way to the solution ? I also need to find the gradient of the function $F_1 (x) = {\lVert  Ax\rVert}_2^2.$ The answer here should be $\nabla F_1(x) = 2A^tAx.$ I do not know how to proceed.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You may find [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) helpful

Comment: Suppose $d=1$. Then (With $a=A$), you have $F(x)=-\frac{1}{2}(ax-b)^2$, and so $F'(x)=-(ax-b)a$, so how can the answer you should get be $\nabla F(x)=Ax-b$?

Comment: It looks like the two answers you "should get"  are incompatible.

Comment: Thanks. I do not know. It is in the book. Maybe it is wrong. What is the correct answer ?

Comment: "The answer I should get is $\nabla F(x) = Ax -b.$" I don't think this is true. I think you should get $\nabla F(x) = -A^T(Ax-b)$ given your definition of $F(x) = -\|Ax-b\|_2^2/2$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a complete answer ? I need to understand the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $F(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|_2^2$. Then we have

$$F(x+h) = -\frac{1}{2}\|A(x+h)-b\|_2^2\\
= -\frac{1}{2}\langle A(x+h)-b, A(x+h)-b\rangle\\
= -\frac{1}{2}\left(\langle Ax, Ax\rangle + \langle Ax, Ah\rangle - \langle Ax, b\rangle + \langle Ah, Ax\rangle + \langle Ah, Ah\rangle - \langle Ah, b\rangle - \langle b, Ax\rangle - \langle b, Ah\rangle + \langle b, b\rangle\right)\\
=-\frac{1}{2}\left( \|Ax-b\|_2^2 + 2\langle Ax, Ah\rangle + \|Ah\|_2^2 -2\langle b, Ah\rangle\right)\\
=F(x) + \langle -A^T(Ax-b),h\rangle-\frac{1}{2}\|Ah\|_2^2\\
=F(x)+ \langle -A^T(Ax-b),h\rangle+o(\|h\|_2^2)$$

Thus the gradient of $F$ is $-A^T(Ax-b)$. For  more examples on this technique, check this webpage http://thousandfold.net/cz/2013/11/12/a-useful-trick-for-computing-gradients-w-r-t-matrix-arguments-with-some-examples/

Another good resource for matrix calculus made easy is here: https://tminka.github.io/papers/matrix/minka-matrix.pdf